# Bootstrap-vue b-table responsive property won't recognize lg or xl values

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm looking to have my table always show the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom without having to scroll down to the very bottom of the table.

If I use the `responsive` property like so:

```
<b-table
  :responsive="md"
  :items="details" 
>
```

`md` and `sm` are recognized: as in, If i go above a browser width of 788px the horizontal scroll bar goes away. However, if I use `lg` or `xl`, the increased breakpoint values aren't recognized. Meaning if I make the browser wider than 788px the horizontal scroll bar is not there.

What am I overlooking here?

[In the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table):

*"Generate a responsive table to make it scroll horizontally. Set to true for an always responsive table, or set it to one of the breakpoints 'sm', 'md', 'lg', or 'xl' to make the table responsive (horizontally scroll) only on screens smaller than the breakpoint. See Responsive tables below for details."*

Comment: Have you tried ```responsive="md"``` instead of ```:responsive="md"```?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-vue table takes responsive values: sm, md, lg, or xl as props of type String. Therefore colon is not valid.

Example:

```
<b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
```

Comment: You are correct. I see what's going on. Whether you pass `responsive` a value or not, this has to do with the horizontal scrollbar at the literal bottom of the page. And those sm/md/lg/xl values do work in that case. However I'm trying to have it so the bottom horizontal scroll bar is ALWAYS showing, without having to scroll to the bottom.